# Separate git accounts on linux server

Tags: linux, git, permissions

I have a lot of git repositories on my linux (ubuntu) server.  I access all of them with the Apache user `www-data`.  This worked great in the past because I was the only web developer.   Now I have more developers and I need to restrict their access to some repositories.  How do I modify my server/permissions/git repositories to accomodate this?

Let me show you the current process I go through to set up a repository.

To set up a new repository for the project `project` on myserver.com, I issue the following commands from terminal:

```
ssh www-data@myserver.com
password: (password for www-data)
cd /var/lib/repositories/
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
git update-server-info
cd /var/www/git.myserver.com/
ln -s /var/lib/repositories/project.git project
```

To deploy the project to the url `http://project.myserver.com`, I issue the following commands from terminal:

```
ssh project@myserver.com
password: (password for project)
cd /var/www/project.myserver.com/public_html/
git init
git remote add origin http://www-data@git.myserver.com/project
git pull origin master
password: (password for www-data)
```

The user `project` needs to know the password for `www-data` to push and pull from the git repository.

How do I modify my server/permissions/gitrepositories so that I can push and pull as `project` instead of `www-data`?

**Additional Notes**

Here's what the vhost entry for `git.myserver.com` looks like

```
<VirtualHost 173.255.230.136:80>
     ServerAdmin support@myserver.com
     ServerName git.myserver.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/git.myserver.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /var/www/git.myserver.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/git.myserver.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The directory `/var/lib/git` is owned by the `www-data` user.  This way, apache can write to the repos via the symbolic link in `/var/www/git.myserver.com/public_html/project` via the url `http://www-data@git.evermight.com/project`

Comment: What's the web server's configuration look like for the `git.myserver.com` host?  And why are you logging on as `www-data`?

Comment: Hi Shane, I answered your question in the additional notes.

Answer (score 0):

First I would have created a separate user for the git login. However that aside, probably the easiest way to manage this is to use something like gitosis which is a simple setup that allows you to do authenticated git access with granular permissions.

This will allow you to give people:

No access, read only, read write. Etc

http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

N.B. just checked the developers site and there are more features in this. Worth looking at for sure https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/

Comment: I have gitosis installed.  What I'm afraid about is I don't understand the `git clone` command.  I've been making new directories and using `git init --bare` to create new repositories.  What are the consequences when I use `git clone`?  And how do I convert existing repositories into a state that appears to have been `git-clone`?

Comment: When you use `git clone` you copy the repository from the remote. So you'd want to use clone on existing repositories. `git init` is for creating new repositories which you then have to add the remote to. If you have existing repositories you should use `git clone` as init will not be using the existing repo it will be generating a new configuration in your current working directory.